# Weird Output Virtual Base Class

Tags: c++, class, virtual

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Student{
protected:
    int roll_no;
public:
    void getNumber(){
        cout << "Enter number\n";
        cin >> roll_no;
    }
    int putNumber(){
        return roll_no;
    }
 };

 class Test:public virtual Student{
protected:
    int m1,m2;
public:
Test(){
    m1=m2=0;
}
Test(int a, int b){
    m1=a;
    m2=b;
}
void display(){
    cout << "Mark 1: " << m1;
    cout << "Mark 2: " << m2;
}
  };

 class Sports:public virtual Student{
protected:
    int score;
public:
Sports(){
    score=0;
}
Sports(int a){
    score=a;
}
void display(){
    cout << "Score: " << score;
}
};

class Total:public virtual Test,public virtual Sports{
private:
    int total;
public:
    Total(){
        total=0;
    }
    int display(){
        total=m1+m2+score;
        return total;
    }
};

int main(){     
Test ob1(10,20);
Sports ob2(50);
Total ob3;
cout << ob3.display() << endl;
}
```

Trying to implement a virtual base class Student. The question is to find the sum of the marks in the Test class and the score in the Sports class. However, i'm getting 0 as the output instead of 80.
Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: what programming language are you using?  You probably want to tag that.

Comment: "virtual base class" does not mean that every object you instantiate uses the same base class objects.

Answer (score 0):

You have some fundamental misunderstandings.

`ob1` and `ob2` are not part of `ob3`. They are completely separate objects. `Total` does have a `Test` part and a `Sports` part, but they are initialized with 0 values because of their default constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You mix the understanding of class-based OOP with the prototype-based OOP. In the latter one objects derive from other objects (entities that are already in memory), hence the derived objects have values of the variables of the base objects they are derived from. C++ is a class-based language in which in-memory objects are instantiation of classes, whereas classes are just declarations of new user-defined types and they are not in-memory objects. Take a look at [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Class-Based_vs._Prototype-Based_Languages) for more details.